# is $f: \Bbb Z_3 → \Bbb Z_9, f(\bar x) \ =[2x]$ a function?

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I am confused about going from $\Bbb Z_3$ to $\Bbb Z_9$ and how that impacts the function. I am not sure where to start.

So far I have:

$$\begin{align}
f(\overline0) &=  [0], \\
f(\overline1) &=  [2], \\
f(\overline2) &=  [4], \\
f(\overline3) &=  [6].
\end{align}$$

I'm not sure how to prove whether or not it is a function.

Comment: Use $ signs for Mathjax

Comment: Check if you get a well-defined output for the residue class $\bar 0 = \bar 3$ regardless of whether you use $0$ or $3$ as representative.

Comment: Side remark: I'm a little puzzled by the question, $\mathbb Z_3$ knows $\bar x\in\{0,1,2\}$ but isn't really aware of "$x$" so in fact do we consider an embedding in $\mathbb Z$ or what to define it ?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\overline{0}=\overline{3}$ in your notation, we should get

$$f(\overline{0})=f(\overline{3})\tag{1}$$

(and so on) for the function $f$ to be *well-defined* (that is, the application of $f$ is independent of the choice of equivalence class representatives). However, the LHS of $(1)$ is $[0]$ in your notation, whereas the RHS is $[6]$, which is not $[0]$. This is because $9\nmid 0-6$.